# Magento 2.3.4 composer update file name too long

Tags: magento2, composer

I am trying to upgrade Magento to 2.3.4.

I'm running composer update from within a docker container on a linux machine and am receiving the following error:

```
error:  cannot create /app/vendor/composer/9b7022b7/Test/Mftf/Test/StorefrontBackordersEnabledOnConfigurationPageAndAppliedFromHomepageToWithConfigurableProductWithDropDownAttributeAndVariablesAssignedToNonDefaultSourceTest.xml
    File name too long

The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

What Docker storage driver are you using? To see what storage driver Docker is currently using, use *docker info* and look for the Storage Driver line.

> When possible, overlay2 is the recommended storage driver. When
>   installing Docker for the first time, overlay2 is used by default.
>   Previously, aufs was used by default when available, but this is no
>   longer the case.

Aufs has a practical filename limit of 242 characters.

> Since aufs has several filename prefixes reserved, the maximum
>   filename length is shorter than ordinary 255. Actually 242

If you are using aufs you should change to overlay2 if possible to avoid this issue.

Comment: I am using overlay2, any other ideas?

Comment: if the limitation is not coming from docker then it must be the container OS. What distro are you running in the container? Or maybe its a crazy composer problem...

Answer (score 0):

**Not working:**

I changed from "aufs" to "overlay" Storage Driver by this guide:

https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/

but it was not working.

---

I found out that the problem is connected to the 160 characters limit length on encrypted unix volumes (Ubuntu in my case)

See: https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/2821